# Auto comment on off-topic questions

Tags: feature-request

#### Background

With reputation over 3000 a user can cast vote whether to Close or ReOpen a question. I think the reputation, for a user, is well-enough understanding the site.

#### Scenario

In a systematic way, question that seems off-topic get its punishment after 5 votes from high privileged users. But without moderator's direct intervention they needs 5 votes. There's no way dictating voting for close, because it's a voluntary work to do. So, if a question got 3 close votes, and nobody is taking their time voting for it, will remain open, and abandon, because they are not WordPress-specific etc. And the person who asked the question doesn't even know what's going on etc. Even the question can get downvote, without any comment. So the person asking question simply puzzled what the hack happened with his/her question.

But he/she can get an answer when the 5 votes completes, and a reason for closing is attached underneath the question.

#### Background #2

If a question is marked duplicate, a comment immediately added underneath saying:

> Possible duplicate of ...

#### Proposal

What if we make an automated comment, like the duplicate thing:

> Your question seems off-topic to the site. Please read FAQ, how a question can be on-topic and How to ask a question here. *bla bla bla*

I found @PieterGoosen doing such ground work tirelessly all the time. Kudos to his effort.

The basis of the comment can be:

- When a single or two 3000+ user[s] downvote and vote closing a Question
- After 5 votes, the directional comment *can be* deleted if there's no reply underneath it

We need to remember that,

- a question can be voted down by anybody with 125+ reputation, we're not counting them, we will count vote from a 3000+ user, and also count a closing vote on the same question from that user.

#### Benefits

- Nothing, but saving some time of a close voter.
- Informing a Question asking person why he/she is getting downvote in his/her question before closing it.

Comment: Just came across this. It should probably be tagged feature-request?

Comment: Good idea. I get a bit tired typing the same cimments All the time. Perhaps there should be some sort of dropdown with standard cimments.